# AS3 - How to save streaming video to an image sequence?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, streaming

When I am streaming a video (using RTMP) in my flash player (AS3) - the frames I see are colored [b]a bit [/b] differently than the frames in the original video !

I would like to somehow save the frames I am showing in my player to an image sequence,

so that I can examine it and understand the difference between each frame I was showing from the stream to the original frame in the original video.

How can this be achieved ? (the video is 5 minutes long, and has 25 frames-per-second).

Comment: If you don't have access to the FMS, then you'll need a third party screen grabber.  If you have access to the FMS, you can adjust the settings to allow you to copy the bitmapData of the frames.  What type of systems are you using.

Comment: I will be using FMS to stream the video, but currently I am simply loading it from the local hard-disk, and playing it in the player. I tried encoding the bitmapData because I have 120,000 frames in the video - so I can't save all the bitmaps to memory, because Flash limits me in memory size

Comment: then just get a frame grab utility.  I use SnapZPro on my mac - it will copy out what ever you want.  There are plenty of other for PCs as well.

Comment: thnx for the tips. but I am afraid that a screen-grab utility will add a performance hit to the rendering of the flash. also - how do I know that the screen-grab utility won't change the colors because of some kind of compression it makes ? also - I have no way of knowing when frames have changed in the original video

Answer (score 0):

First you should set the following flags on the fms script, which allows you to access the streaming video or audio.

```
application.onConnect = function(client,....)
{
...
    client.audioSampleAccess = "/";
    client.videoSampleAccess = "/";

}
```

Secondly on the client side, you may use the BitMapData.draw method to capture the video from the VideoDisplayObject

```
    var snapshot:BitmapData = new BitmapData(video.width, video.height); 
    snapshot.draw(videoDisplay);
```